# Create a Primary Key on a large table (6Million records) without locking the table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, primary-key-design

I want to create a Primary Key on a table with 6 Million records, but when I execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE schema_name.table_name ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_name PRIMARY KEY (field_pkey_name);
```

It's locking my table and alter table does not finish executing...

Comment: If it doesn't ever finish, then it must be blocked by something else holding a conflicting lock.  You will probably need to resolve this before any method is going to work.  Laurenz's method only needs a strong lock for a fraction of a second, but it still does need to take a strong lock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do it in two steps:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY pkey_name
   ON schema_name.table_name (field_pkey_name);

ALTER TABLE schema_name.table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_name PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX pkey_name;
```

It will still take a long time (even longer), but the table will not be locked for a long time.

Comment: Actually, the table will be locked. However, for a very short time as the index is already built.